# How to obtain a set of threshold filters to optimize a target?

Tags: python, optimization, filter

I have a dataset of length N, with M features and 1 output-target.

I want a set of filters that are 'basic' decision boundaries for the M features that give me at least, say 10% of my N samples. For example, for feature M_1, a threshold of 0.1 where x>=0.1 is accepted and x<0.1 is rejected; I would like this threshold and direction for each filter. It would be trivial to do this for each feature individually, but I believe the best filter combination will not be all individual best filters combined.

How would I go about doing this? Is there something in sklearn or another python library that would help do this quickly?

I can do this "manually" by selecting A thresholds-levels and then just iterating through every combination of M features and A thresholds, but this gives an outrageously humungous number of combinations to iterate through. I was wondering if there was some math/compsci technique I could use to achieve my desired results faster

Comment: `array[array < 0.1] = 0` thresholding

Comment: @nimrobotics thank you for commenting, but I wasn't looking for the trivial syntax on how to filter when given a threshold. I was looking for guidance on how to find this 0.1 threshold-value for M-features that optimizes an output-target, without brute forcing A thresholds (say 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 0.9 on feature M_1 that ranges from 0 to 1) and M-features which gives M^A combinations.